# What am I? Question

Tags: word

I am the beginning of eternity. 
I am the beginning of the end.

Yet I am the end of space and time.

What am I?

Clue:a letter might answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this is an old chestnut. You are obviously

> The letter e

Answer (score 0):

You are the letter:

> **E**

I am the beginning of the of eternity

> Eternity starts with E

I am the beginning of the end

> The end also starts with the letter E

Yet I am the end of space and time

> Space and time ends with the letter E